# AWS RDS documentation leads to BASH syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

When following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html) and this command

```
sudo mysqldump --databases world --single-transaction --compress --order-by-primary –u <local_user> -p<local_password> 
   | mysql --host=hostname –-port=3306 –u <RDS_user_name> –p<RDS_password>
```

BASH returns the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Can you help me understand why?

After deleting greater than / less than symbols from command, now returns

```
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Which is a pipe error.

How shall I proceed?

Comment: I'm guessing you entered that as two commands. It's meant as one, so don't press return before the `|`.

Comment: I have copied/pasted and hand typed it as one line with the same results.

Comment: keep it on 2 lines, and add a '\' char at the end of the first line. No trailing spaces or tabs allowed! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Did you replace all the `<xxx>` placeholders with actual values, without the `<` and `>` characters?

Comment: thank you Barmar, I had not replaced the < >